# Escape too many whitespaces in a CMD Command to use with Run Method

Tags: cmd, vbscript, escaping, whitespace

I have following large command which works fine when I type in CMD Window and manually run:

```
CMD /C ""C:\Windows\SysWOW64\CSCRIPT" "F:\Downloads\Window Scripting Object\Window Scripting.vbs"" > "C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Temp\FOREGROUND_WINDOW.txt"
```

As I have to run this command from a VBScript, I tried many times to escape whitespaces like below:

```
WshShell.Run "CMD /C """"C:\Windows\SysWOW64\CSCRIPT"" ""F:\Downloads\Window Scripting Object\Window Scripting.vbs"""" > ""C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Temp\FOREGROUND_WINDOW.txt""", 0, True

WshShell.Run "CMD /C """"C:\Windows\SysWOW64\CSCRIPT"""" """"F:\Downloads\Window Scripting Object\Window Scripting.vbs"""" > ""C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Temp\FOREGROUND_WINDOW.txt""", 0, True

WshShell.Run "CMD /C """"C:\Windows\SysWOW64\CSCRIPT"" ""F:\Downloads\Window Scripting Object\Window Scripting.vbs"""""" > """"C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Temp\FOREGROUND_WINDOW.txt""", 0, True
```

But unfortunately any of those commands didn't work as I expected.

Can someone help me in escaping whitespaces in this large command?

Comment: Could you explain why you think you should be invoking the 32-bit version of `CScript.exe` on a 64-bit Operating System? Also if there really is a need to bypass the built-in file system redirector, _which I currently doubt_, you don't do it like that, you use the special, not visible, virtual directory alias, `%WinDir%\Sysnative`.

Comment: @Compo I have to call another VBScript, which uses my 32-bit COM Wrapper. If I run it from 64-bit wscript / cscript, it throws the error `Could not create object named WindowsScriptingObject`. Because the OS I am running is Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit Service Pack 1.

Comment: Either way, you should be using `Sysnative` or ensuring that the initial  `Cmd.exe` instance is 32-bit. I note that you've doublequoted things which don't require it, while it's good to be robust, if you're doubling them all up why not reduce them to that which is required, `Cmd /C CScript "F:\Downloads\Window Scripting Object\Window Scripting.vbs" //Nologo>C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Temp\FOREGROUND_WINDOW.txt`. Additionally, I would expect that you should be able to invoke `CScript` directly, it should spawn and run in its own `Cmd.exe` instance.

Comment: Your last attempt contains unbalanced quotes...

Comment: I still cannot balance quotes in this command. Please give me a hint. :-/

Comment: Is there any reason for `CMD /C `?

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to escape all double quotes successfully.

```
WshShell.Run "CMD /C ""C:\Windows\SysWOW64\CSCRIPT ""F:\Downloads\Window Scripting Object\Window Scripting.vbs"""""" > ""C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Temp\FOREGROUND_WINDOW.txt""", 0, True
```